# JHipster Springboot application Failed with Heroku

Tags: spring-boot, heroku, jhipster

I tried to deploy SpringBoot app generated by JHipster to Heroku, but it is failed because this error, I used JHipster way to deploy my app https://www.jhipster.tech/heroku/ , any ideas ? :

```
2018-04-06T21:28:57.412612+00:00 app[web.1]: 21:28:57.412 [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed

2018-04-06T21:28:57.412615+00:00 app[web.1]: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load property source from location 'classpath:/config/application-prod.yml'

2018-04-06T21:28:57.412617+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.loadIntoGroup(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:476)

2018-04-06T21:28:57.412618+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.load(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:450)

2018-04-06T21:28:57.412619+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.load(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:386)

2018-04-06T21:28:57.412620+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.addPropertySources(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:225)

2018-04-06T21:28:57.412621+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.postProcessEnvironment(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:195)

2018-04-06T21:28:57.412626+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:182)

2018-04-06T21:28:57.412627+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:168)

2018-04-06T21:28:57.412628+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
```

Comment: Which deployment method did you use for deploying to Heroku (compile locally or compile on Heroku)?

Comment: compile on heroku

Comment: I totally depends on your version and on options you selected, there is no way we can help you with so little information

Comment: what information you needed ? I can post any

Comment: Please add the contents of your project's `.yo-rc.json` to the post